# Override save for model

Tags: python, django, django-models, overriding, models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number_in_order = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='employees_photo/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.number_in_order = self.id
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Why number_in_order field does not appropriate the value of id field

Comment: If it's a new object, it won't have an id. Save it first to get an id, then edit number_in_order, then save it again. Or do a queryset.update after the first save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `self.number_in_order` before calling the super of save. So at the time of assigning, you do not have value in `self.id`. Value of `id` is decided by the database.